# Aurelia custom element (bootstrap-select) not working properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, aurelia

I was trying to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29883282/two-way-binding-not-working-on-bootstrap-select-with-aurelia) solution into my project but using ES1015 not ESNext and I've not been able to get the `attached` life cycle callback. all the previous callbacks are called: `constructor`, `created`, `bind`.

This is my code for the view model:

```
import {decorators, customElement, bindable, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import * as selectpicker from 'bootstrap-select';
import $ from 'jquery';

export let BootStrapSelectPicker = decorators(
  customElement('select-picker'),
  bindable({name: 'selectableValues', defaultValue: null}),
  bindable({name: 'modelToBind', defaultValue: null}),
  inject(Element)
).on(class {
  constructor(element) {
    console.log("constructor");
    this.element = element;
  }

  created() {
    console.log(".....created");
  }

  bind() {
    console.log("--------binded");
  }

  attached() {
    //im supposed to create the element here
  }

});
```

and the code for the view:

```
<template>
  <select value.bind="modelToBind">
    <option value.bind="null">Selecciona un genero</option>
    <option repeat.for="p of selectableValues" value.bind="p.key">${p.text}</option>
  </select>
</template>
```

Any help will be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: it works fine for me https://gist.run/?id=b8a5f453ba3656c5b27c8a0a1f7b4490. Are you sure you are not missing something somewhere else?

Comment: I see. well, I am using that custom element inside an component without model-view. I tried placing my component on a different place and the attached callback got called :/

Comment: perhaps there's an error in your view-only component

Comment: @FabioLuz after some debugging I found something interesting. The attached method is called if and only if I place the custom element outside my default layout view. https://gist.run/?id=277f8775e729ca87387f5913ce6fd201